# How can i get assigned fields and value through Action<T>?

Tags: c#, orm

```
public int Update(Action<T> updateAction, Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)

Update(m => { m.Email = "sample@abc.com"; m.FullName = "jim green"; }, m=>m.UserID==1);
```

I encapsulates the underlying method for updating the specified field in a table, so I used the Action, I hope to get assigned field through Action, and then the field name and field values are extracted in a Dictionary dictionary collection, what method can be used to get the results I want?

Comment: Dictionary<string object>  dictionary collection

Comment: Could you elaborate your question, especially the part where you said "get assigned field through Action, and then the field name and field values are extracted in a Dictionary dictionary collection"

Comment: I want to get the field of ’Email’ and ’FullName’ that appeared in the action,m => { m.Email = "sample@abc.com"; m.FullName = "jim green"; }

Comment: Method `Update` takes an action, `m` is unknown until `updateAction` is called. Also where does the dictionary come from?

Comment: i want to get field name and field value and put the pair into a dictionary,the dictionary<string,object> instance  will be created,the dictionary is not the point,it is only a collection that storage the field name and field value,the point is how to get field name and field value by the action<T>

Comment: how I did it now. First, create an object that is type of T,uses the reflection to empty all the fields, and then call updateAction,  uses the reflection to extract the fields that are not empty. This is an Inefficient way,any better ways?

Comment: Why don't you post you current solution, I'm afraid I still don't get it.